# Javascript method syntax - correct term for lowerUpper formatting

Tags: javascript, syntax, methodology

CSS uses hyphens to separate words:

```
.class_name{background-color:#000;}
```

Javascript uses lowerUpper formatting:

```
document.getElementById("my_div").style.backgroundColor
```

But what is the lowerUpper formatting syntax called?

I read it somewhere, in the context of "remember to **_** the style property because javascript doesn't use hyphens".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called CamelCase. Take a look at wikipedia for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: That's the ticket, thanks friedi. It's been bugging me all afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [Douglas Crockford's code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)  for javascript. I also use his [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) tool to validate following those conventions.

JSLint can be too radical and restrictive for many developers, then [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) can be better choice.

There is also the [Online Javascript Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) which seems to use all the Douglas Crockford conventions to format the code. It does not address the naming of variables and functions though.